# What do we need for using JIRA Rest Java Client Library?

Tags: java, jira

I am going to make a simple app to connect to JIRA using JIRA Rest Java Client Library.
But I don't know what all things (APIs, jars, etc) besides `jira-rest-java-client-0.6-m8.jar` I require for it.

I don't know the starting point. I have seen the tutorial at their website and used the same code after after installing maven plugin in my eclipse.

Comment: And what *concrete* problem do you have?

Comment: Or you could formulate a concrete question that we can answer.

Comment: That is not the kind of specific question that is [on-topic here at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up a test project using that lib and the suggested maven dependencies from their site using the the milestone 4.

This link should help you figure out the dependencies you need to include in your pom.xml:

http://www.versioneye.com/package/com~atlassian~jira--jira-rest-java-client/version/0~6-m8